# Create multiple selects with options with jquery or angularJS from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

i need help. I would like to create dynamically selects with options depending the data i get from my REST API. The data is a JSONObject. How can i inject dynamically those selects into my html. Here is an example:

My JSON i get from REST API:

```
{
  "Projects":[
          "Project A",
          "Project B",
          "Project C"
         ],
  "Variant":[
          "Variant A",
          "Variant B"
          ],
  "Information":[
            "Info 1",
            "Info 2"
            ],
  "Links":[
        "Link 1",
        "Link 2"]
}
```

Thats my template:

```
<div class="ui-field-contain" id="project-names">

</div>
```

Now i want to use jquery or angularjs to generate the selects Project, Variant, Information and Links, with their options.

It should be something like that:

```
<div class="ui-field-contain" id="project-names">
  <label for="project">Project:</label> 
  <select name="project" id="project" data-native-menu="false">
    <option value="Project A">Project A</option>
    <option value="Project B">Project B</option>
    <option value="Project C">Project C</option>
  </select> 
  <label for="variant">Variant:</label> 
  <select name="variant" id="variant" data-native-menu="false">
    <option value="Variant A">Variant A</option>
    <option value="Variant B">Variant B</option>
  </select>
  <label for="Information">Information:</label> 
  <select name="Information" id="Information" data-native-menu="false">
    <option value="Info A">Info A</option>
    <option value="Info B">Info B</option>
  </select> 
  <label for="select-1">Link:</label> 
  <select name="Link"   id="Link" data-native-menu="false">
    <option value="Link A">Link A</option>
    <option value="Link B">Link B</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Is this possible?

Thanks.

EDIT My code so far:
    var $htmlProjectNames = $("#project-names");
    $btnGetProjects.on('click', function() {

```
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url: '/RestFulApi/api/v1/mcd/get-projects',
        datatype : "json",
        success : function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(prefix, project) {

                $htmlProjectNames.append(
                        '<label for' + perfix +'>' + prefix +'</label>\n'+
                        '<select name="'+prefix+ 'id="' + prefix +'"' + 'data-native-menu="false">'


                );

            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Can u make a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

> ```
> $.ajax({
>         type : 'GET',
>         url: '/RestFulApi/api/v1/mcd/get-projects',
>         datatype : "json",
>         success : function(data) {
>             $.each(data, function (key, values) {
>                 var template = '<label for="' + key.toLowerCase() + '">' + key + ':</label>' +
>                             '<select name="' + key.toLowerCase() + '" id="' + key + '" data-native-menu="false">';
>                 for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++){
>                     template = template + '<option value="' + values[i] + '">' + values[i] + '</option>';
>                 }
>                 template = template + '</select>';
>                 $("div#project-names").append(template);
>             });
>         }
>     });
> ```